# scipy.spatial.ckdtree running slowly

Tags: python, performance, scipy

I've been using `spatial.cKDTree` in `scipy` to calculate distances between points. It has always run very quickly (~1 s) for my typical data sets (finding distances for ~1000 points to an array of ~1e6 points).

I'm running this code in python 2.7.6 on a computer with Ubuntu 14.10. Up until this morning, I had managed most python packages with `apt-get`, including `scipy` and `numpy`. I wanted up-to-date versions of a few packages though, so I decided to packages installed in `/usr/lib/python2.7/` by `apt-get`, and re-installed all packages with `pip install` (taking care of `scipy` dependencies like `liblapack-dev` with `apt-get`, as necessary). Everything installed and is importable without a problem.

```
import scipy
import cython
scipy.__version__
'0.16.0'
cython.__version__
'0.22.1'
```

Now, running `spatial.cKDTree` on the same size data sets is going really slowly. I'm seeing run time of ~500 s rather than ~1 s. I'm having trouble figuring out what is going on.

Any suggestions as to what I might have done in installing using `pip` rather than `apt-get` that would have caused `scipy.spatial.cKDTree` to run so slowly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In `0.16.x` I added options to build the `cKDTree` with median or sliding midpoint rules, as well as choosing whether to recompute the bounding hyperrectangle at each node in the kd-tree. The defaults are based on experiences about the performance of `scipy.spatial.cKDTree` and `sklearn.neighbors.KDTree`. In some contrived cases (data that are highly streched along a dimension) it can have negative impact, but usually it should be faster. Experiment with bulding the `cKDTree` with `balanced_tree=False` and/or `compact_nodes=False`. Setting both to `False` gives you the same behavior as `0.15.x`. Unfortunately it is difficult to set defaults that make everyone happy because the performance depends on the data.

Also note that with `balanced_tree=True` we compute medians by quickselect when the kd-tree is constructed. If the data for some reason is pre-sorted, it will be very slow. In this case it will help to shuffle the rows of the input data. Or you can set `balanced_tree=False` to avoid the partial quicksorts.

There is also a new option to multithread the nearest-neighbor query. Try to call `query` with `n_jobs=-1` and see if it helps for you.

**Update June 2020:**
SciPy 1.5.0 will use a new algorithm (introselect based partial sort, from C++ STL) which solves the problems reported here.

Comment: Thanks, switching both balanced_tree and compact_nodes to False gave me the same behavior I'd had before. My data are not stretched in one direction, so I'll have to do some more reading on cKDTree to figure out why those parameters caused such a slowdown for my problem.

Comment: Are your data points sorted in advance? E.g. do they come from a grid? In that case the partial sort used to split nodes might become quadratic in complexity.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Yes, my data come from a grid, and I missed the import of the second paragraph of your answer because I was not intentionally sorting the data. Nonetheless, the data are already sorted.

Comment: Normally you don't need a kd-tree to search for k-NN in a grid because you can do that with divisions and roundings, which would be O(n) instead of O(n log n). But it might be a more common (ab)use of ```cKDTree``` than I thought. If it turns out to be a problem for a lot of people, we can change the default back to ```balanced_tree=False``` or do some other tricks to check or correct for this problem.

Comment: In my case, I'm keeping about 1-2% of irregularly spaced points that come from a grid, based on meeting some selection criteria. I came across `cKDTree` when I needed to do something more sophisticated than the grid coordinates to array coordinates approach you mention.

Comment: Still a very relevant answer! I was seeing my `cKDTree` script complete in 5sec on one machine, then 8min on another machine - turns out `scipy==0.13` default setup handles my data (curvilinear coordinates grid) *much* better than `scipy==1.0.0` defaults. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

In the next release of SciPy, balanced kd-trees will be created with introselect instead of quickselect, which is much faster on structured datasets. If you use cKDTree on a structured data set such as an image or a grid, you can look forward to a major boost in performance. It is already available if you build SciPy from its master branch on GitHub.