# cartopy hanging during transform

Tags: cartopy

I've installed cartopy using miniconda2. When running a small sample, the code never gets past the image transform on the plt.imshow line, it just hangs there using 100% CPU. Here's the code:

```
#!~/miniconda2/bin/python
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time
import sys

print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

fname = '2016_2_24_1200_MTSAT3_10_S1_grid.jpeg'

img = plt.imread(fname)

print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

img_proj = ccrs.Geostationary(satellite_height=35786000)
img_extent = (-5500000, 5500000, -5500000, 5500000)

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Miller())
ax.coastlines()
ax.set_global()
origin = 'upper'

print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

plt.imshow(img, transform=img_proj, extent=img_extent, origin=origin, cmap='gray')
fig.savefig('html/test.jpg')
```

Any clue anyone?

Comment: Is the image itself public domain? Can this be reproduced by exchanging the image for a ``numpy.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)``?

Comment: Here's a file you can use: http://wx.inside.net/sat/2016_2_26_1000_MTSAT3_7_S1_grid.jpeg

Comment: I've in the meantime figured out that it's only the Geostationary transform that is causing this issue. It usually fails after several hours with an error 11, whatever that means. All other transforms are reasonably quick and behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

So I had a similar problem with image transforms in Cartopy, I've fixed the issue by adding a keyword to a Cartopy script. In your Python installation directory go to `Lib\site-packages\cartopy`. The file you need to edit is `img_transform.py` and you also need to delete `img_transform.pyc` to make it recompile with the change you make.

Within `img_transform.pyc` the line you need to edit is:

```
kdtree = scipy.spatial.cKDTree(xyz)
```

which is line 288 in Cartopy v0.14.2 (latest at time of writing).

change this line to:

```
kdtree = scipy.spatial.cKDTree(xyz, balanced_tree=False)
```

This switches off a new default that was introduced in SciPy v0.16 (see [scipy.spatial.ckdtree running slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31819778/scipy-spatial-ckdtree-running-slowly)).

For me this made something which took >24 hours return to taking ~3 minutes-hope it works for you!

Comment: Hi Siyh
Thanks for pointing this out, and contributing the related https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/744.
I really need to get that fix  merged now one way or another, so are you ready to complete, or can we just go ahead with https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/pull/510, in which I tried to include your proposal ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi pp-mo, I've tried to submit the CLA form (emailed it to @pelson, couldn't find any info on where else to send it) which I understand is needed for the fix to be accepted, waiting on a response. I'm unfamiliar with GitHub, is there anything else I can/need to do to get the change merged?

Comment: Thanks Siyh.
I work with @pelson, so I will try to move it along !

Comment: There is no more required Github magic, but there were some issues raised which I addressed in my 'poached' version (I was just proposing a shortcut in case we didn't hear from you).  If you fix those we can merge your PR (and I'll rebase mine onto yours).  We could just merge mine, but I think we'd rather welcome you as a "proper" contributor.

Comment: Contributor added ! https://github.com/SciTools/scitools.org.uk/pull/132 
Congratulations Siyh!
Now just revisit your PR + we can merge it.